# How to call an Object method when its hidden

Tags: c#, .net

For example, if I have a class that creates the following method:

```
public new string ToString() {
//some code
}
```

But let's say that I needed to call the ToString method from the Object class. How would I do that?

Comment: can you explain more, whats your problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should cast to the `Object` and then call the method:

```
class A
{
    public new string ToString()
    {
        return "bugaga!";
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var a = new A();

    Console.WriteLine(a.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(a); // here object 'a' will be casted to object
}
```

output:

```
bugaga!
ConsoleApplication4.Program+A
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `((Object)myvariable).ToString()`, casting back to the base.

More here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6fawty39(v=vs.100).aspx

Are you sure you really want to create a *new* `ToString()` on your class though? It's common to *override* the original implementation instead:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173154(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I would bet this is a sanitized example.